# TypeScript enum to specific object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have the following TypeScript enum:

```
export declare enum SupportedLanguages {
    en,
    fr
}
```

If I import it in my react application and `console.log` it, I will get the following object returned:

```
{
  en: "en", 
  fr: "fr"
}
```

How can I manipulate it, so that I get the following object returned?

```
{
  en: "",
  fr: ""
}
```

I tried it with `const Lang = Object.keys(SupportedLanguages)` and also with `.map()` but I did not get the expected object returned.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a set?

Comment: Enum on the level of TS is a type and a structure, you cannot enumarate over it. But you can create a type and a data with exact fields as enum has `type ObjFromEnum = Record<SupportedLanguages, ''>
const obj: ObjFromEnum = {
    [SupportedLanguages.en]: '',
    [SupportedLanguages.fr]: '',
};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just looking to get a new object with all the data as empty strings?

```
var supportedLanguages = {
  en: "en", 
  fr: "fr"
};

var result = Object.keys(supportedLanguages)
    .reduce((accum, key) => 
        Object.assign(accum, { [key]: "" })
    , {});

console.log(result); // { "en": "", "fr": "" }
```

Comment: Even simpler: `Object.keys(supportedLanguages).reduce((a,k)=>Object.assign(a,{[k]:''}),{})`

Answer (score 3):

You can get the keys, and map them to a tupple of `[key, '']`, and convert back to an object with [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const supportedLanguages = {
  en: "en", 
  fr: "fr"
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.keys(supportedLanguages)
    .map(k => [k, ''])
);

console.log(result);
```

If you receive an error like this:

> TS2550: Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to 'es2019' or later.

Add `es2019` to `compilerOptions.lib` in your project's `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2019"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `typescript` I am using below solution,

```
export declare enum SupportedLanguages {
    en="",
    fr=""
}
```

Also you can use lib. for some default methods. https://www.npmjs.com/package/enum-values

Answer (score 1):

You could translate the object to a key arr → set → map.

Here are some trivial translation functions:

```js
const keySet   = o => new Set(Object.keys(o))
const arrToMap = a => a.reduce((a, k) => Object.assign(a, { [k]: '' }), {})
const setToMap = s => arrToMap([...s])
const keyMap   = o => setToMap(keySet(o))


const SupportedLanguages = {
  en : "en",
  fr : "fr"
}

console.log(Object.keys(SupportedLanguages)) // arr
console.log([...keySet(SupportedLanguages)]) // set
console.log(keyMap(SupportedLanguages))      // obj
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```